Google OAuth 2.0 integration in ASP.NET Core Web API project in C#
I'm getting the error when trying to log in with google .
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: The oauth state was missing or invalid.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

This is the part in program.cs where I integrated the Google options just as it said in the Microsoft docs (besides that, I'm also using JWT token auth in case the user does not want to log in with Google).
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["JWTToken"];
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
    
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = jwtSettings["Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = jwtSettings["Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key.ToString()!)),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
}).AddGoogle(options =>
{
    var googleAuth = builder.Configuration.GetSection("GoogleAuth");
    options.ClientId = googleAuth["ClientId"]!;
    options.ClientSecret = googleAuth["ClientSecret"]!;
    
});

These are my endpoints in the backend - this is my controller settings:
[EnableCors("AllowVueApp")]
[Route("api/user")]
[ApiController]

[HttpGet("signin-google")]
public IActionResult GoogleLogIn()
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action("GoogleResponse", "Authentication");
    Console.WriteLine($"Redirect URL: {redirectUrl}");
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl };
    return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

[HttpGet("google-response")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleResponse()
{
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    var claims = result.Principal?.Identities
            .FirstOrDefault()?.Claims.Select(claim => new
            {
                claim.Issuer,
                claim.OriginalIssuer,
                claim.Type,
                claim.Value
            });
    
    return Ok(claims);
}

And this is my endpoint redirection from the frontend in my vue.js file:
googleLogIn() {
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:5043/signin-google';
}

This is my authorized URI in my Google console:

Why do I get the error and how to solve it?
I searched for a bunch of tutorials but i could not find anything usefull .

you can't use localhost (think about which machine is localhost from the google server point of wiev)

maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/76427357/1841839

There could be two reasons
Check Google authentication settings are correct in your startup class.
Verify your redirect URL registered in your Google Developer Console match with the configured in your application
